# Should we use django authentication for all users of a site?

Tags: python, django, authentication, user-controls, django-users

I have just started developing a bookstore site with Django and I have a question about user authentication.
I want users to have a wallet, shopping cart and additional information for their account such as profile picture, phone number, address, etc. to buy books.

And now I am faced with the dilemma of whether to change the User model itself, or create a Profiles model for each and link it to the User model, or create a separate model (in other words, the authentication system) and do everything from scratch.

Now I have started building a separate authentication system. Everything was going well until I had problems in sending and receiving user data in the template contexts.

**Finally, in general, I want to know if Django authentication system is really suitable for all users of a site?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django is one of the most battle-hardened and well tested 'batteries-included' frameworks out there, so the built-in Authentication is more than acceptable. [The Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/) have an overview, with a guide on how to extend.

You can make an assessment of 3rd party packages relating to authentication [here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/authentication/), and make a judgement as to whether or not any of these packages are suited to your e-commerce use-case.

With regards to your User model, its widely considered best practice to **begin** your project with a custom user model (i.e. before your first migration). The official docs even state this, however some people still prefer the 'old' way of doing this, which is to create a separate 'one-to-one' profile model.

[Here](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model) is a tutorial about beginning a project with a custom User model.
[Here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/04/26/how-switch-custom-django-user-model-mid-project/) is one about changing mid-project.

Comment: This is a great answer. You should indeed create your own User model as stated in the documentation. This is the best solution in the long-run.

Comment: Always use a custom User models (either extending BaseUser or AbstractBaseUser). EVERY time I’ve skipped this, thinking I wouldn’t need it, I have regretted it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fortunately, I used a custom user first and even used the allauth third-party package to strengthen the authentication system, and according to your answer, my job became easier.

Answer (score 0):

If the default Django's `User` model does not contain everything you need, you can always extend it with your own model. Django docs have it covered with some examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

By extending the `User` model you can add additional fields and/or functions to the `User` model (for example, you can add an image, description, age, relationship status, etc.).

Having said that, I really recommend using Django's authentication backend. It's well-tested and secure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fortunately, I used a custom user first of all, so let's go to Django himself!